# How can I validate OpenId token in C#?

Tags: c#, openid, token

I am trying to validate using this parameters:

```
"openid.mode=check_authentication"<br>
+ "&openid.assoc_handle=" + txtAssocHandle.Text<br>
+ "&openid.response_nonce=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtNonce.Text)<br>
+ "&openid.op_endpoint=" + txtEndpoint.Text<br>
+ "&openid.sig=" + txtSignature.Text<br>
+ "&openid.signed=mode,identity,return_to";
```

and it returns

```
is_valid:false
ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
```

what am I doing wrong here?
the txt fields are being filled with login response values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your openid.signed argument needs to be exactly what the OP sent to your RP rather than this incomplete hard-coded list of 3 parameters, for one thing.  All your arguments should be URL encoded as well, not just your nonce.

There is a lot more to validating an OpenID token than just sending it back to the OP using "dumb mode".  What are you trying to do?

Have you considered using an [OpenID library](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)?  Seriously, getting OpenID right (meaning secure, and interoperable) is a big job.  Way bigger than assembling just the right query string. :)

Comment: I want user to login, then I take the token, pass it to a web service, then the web service must validate this token.
I've tried this library, but I didn't find any help to validate the token.

Comment: Are you passing it to a web service *just* to validate the token, or because you're using the token to authorize a request that is made on the user's behalf?

Comment: I am using the token as parameter for every method to verify if user is authorized to access that method.

Comment: actually, webservice must only verify if the user is logged in the openid server, because the authorization will be done in other way.

Comment: OpenID was *not* designed for this, and you'll run into trouble when you send the same OpenID assertion for more than one web service call since direct verification should only work *once* per assertion. What you're doing is really a scenario better covered by OAuth IMO.